# How we can add a field to JSON stream in spring XD?

Tags: groovy, spring-xd

How I can add a timestamp field if it doesn't exist in JSON stream in spring xd, I think we can use a using groovy script for that.

Suppose my JSON stream is `{node : value}` I want to add one more field timestamp if it does't exist `{node : value, timestamp : 23432434}`

`stream create example --definition "http | transform --script='file:addTime.groovy'" --deploy`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, use a `JsonToObjectTransformer` to transform to a `LinkedHashMap`; then `put` the new map entry if absent, then an `ObjectToJsonTransformer`.

Comment: It was not working for me, i did like this `@Grab("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json") def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper(); def payload = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload); payload.put("Time", System.nanoTime()); payload = JsonOutput.toJson(payload);` I am new to groovy programming may be i'm doing it wrong.